# Draw Amplitude and Phase Spectrum for given signal

Tags: signal, signal-processing, fourier

[image]

The above problem was asked in my class test. I understand that this waveform has a hidden symmetry.

x(t) = Square wave with p-p A + (A/10)

So, I can write fourier series expansion for it. As square wave contains odd half wave symmetry, so only odd harmonics of sin are present.

x(t) = sum[(2A/npi)sinnwt] + (A/10)

I am stuck here. How can I draw amplitude and phase spectrum from here?

A plot will be really helpful to understand.

Comment: Is it truly a 50% duty square wave - it doesn't look that way how it has been drawn.

Comment: T/2 and T is labelled in the diagram.

Comment: Then what is this hidden symmetry that you mention. Think about what I'm saying.

Comment: hidden symmetry refers to square wave with dc offset. My instructor used a special name for such waveforms in class.

Comment: is that graph to scale, or is that middle crossing at T/2 ?

Comment: There is middle crossing at T/2. Its a square wave with DC offset.